# Insert a sound after a Toast, Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I did a program like memory game. I have a problem. I want to insert a sound (a beep or something that says "you lose") but I have no idea how to do it. I read around but was everything only for specific project. I try with Toolkit (I read around something) but I did not resolve anything. Can you help me? Here is the code.

```
 Timer t = new Timer(false);
 t.schedule(tt, 1000);

 if (turns == homemanytries.intValue()) {
     Context context = getApplicationContext();
     CharSequence text = "Woah, took you too much tries!";
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
     toast.show();
     onCreate(null);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play sound use below code, Tutorial [here](http://javapapers.com/android/how-to-play-audio-in-android/)
Get an audio with sound of you loose and replace it in R.raw.loose

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.you_loose);
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beep);
mp.setVolume(1f, 1f); //if you want to play sound when volume is 0
mp.start();
```